# Vue.js with System.js how to run a local example

Tags: vue.js, system.js

I would like to run locally a `Vue.js/System.js` demo app I just got recently, never used `System.js` before (and I'll not...)

I only want to run this demo, before switching it to webpack...
There is no npm script (so no install, no run dev)

How should I run it to display in my local browser?
Anything to do before running? (there is no documentation on it..)

```
demo
    app
      components
      About
      App
      ..
      index.js
    routes
      Home
      ...
      index.js
    style
      main.css
  assets
    home
      ...
    ...
  documentation
    ...
  libs
  favicon.ico
  index.html
  readme.html
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the `system.config`:

```js
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true
    , map: {
        'app': './app'
        , 'js': '/libs/js'
        , 'style': '/libs/css'
        , 'theme': '/app/theme'
        , 'babel': '/libs/js/babel-core'
        , 'components': '/app/components',
        'routes': '/app/routes',
    },
    transpiler: 'babel'
    , meta: {
        'js/*.js': {
            format: 'global'
        }
    }
});

System.import('/app/index.js');
```

And the `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="author" content="BelosTemas">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test template</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/style/main.css" id="theme-stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <app></app>
    </div>
    <!-- system -->
    <script src="/libs/js/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/system.config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2

I changed the script src paths in the index.html relative paths  (src='./)
now the script file is located .. but it's not executed correctly, CORS related issue ..

**Error:**

```
system.js:5 Failed to load file:///app/index.js: Cross origin requests
are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, 
chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways. It depends on what the application depends on. Basically just configure SystemJS using `SystemJS.config({packages:{"app": {"main": "app/components/index.js"}}})`

Comment: thanks @Aluan , I updated my question with the current system.config and index.html
When requesting index.html in my browser ( file://... ) I get 2  errosr :   Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///libs/js/system.js”.  AND  Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///app/system.config.js”.

Comment: Why use `src` attributes with a leading `/`? Also, on an unrelated note, the `meta` config looks fishy.

Comment: fixed the meta in index.html , (copy/paste nug..). src attributes with leading / ... it's the original way it was written...

Comment: live-server is one of best solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Answer (score 2):

I solved it , installing a lightweight web server

```
npm install -g live-server
```

then in the console, going to my app directory, I just run it

```
live-server
```

default browser is open with http://localhost:8080 
bonus : hot reloading !